# How to print matching value of patterned field separator in AWK

Tags: awk

In the below command,

`cat abc.txt|awk -F"[0-9]+."  '{print FS $3}'`

Here `FS` prints `[0-9]+.`. However, I want the `awk` to print the matched value by that field separator e.g. "99." . Any idea how can I do it?

Say `abc.txt` has this below. I want to separate second sentences using number. as `FS` and print that number. in the output. basically want to print the value of `FS` ...such need came across in several places.

```
14. Animals  20. features           
1. tiger   1. wild animal
2. cat     2. domestic animal
3. parrot  3. bird with wings
```

Comment: Welcome to U & L SE. Please paste the contents of `abc.txt` file and also paste a sample input and the output that you are expecting by [editing](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/179343/edit) your question.

Answer (score 2):

You don't want the value of `FS`; you want the string which matched `FS` (which can be different strings on the same line):

```
> awk -F"[0-9]+." '{ printf "line %3d.: ",NR; 
  if (NF==1) { print "No FS match in this line"; next; }; str=$0; 
  for(j=1;j<NF;j++) { match(str, FS); fs_str=substr(str, RSTART, RLENGTH); 
  printf "_%s_, ",fs_str; str=substr(str, RSTART+RLENGTH)}; print ""; }' file
line   1.: _14._, _20._, 
line   2.: _1._, _1._, 
line   3.: _2._, _2._, 
line   4.: _3._, _3._,
```

Comment: This gave me whole explanations ...Hauke, highly appreciated for your prompt and expert reply.

Comment: @Shiva If this solves your problem then you should accept the answer so that the other readers can see that this question is done. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

I like `gawk`'s [FPAT](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Splitting-By-Content.html) for this

```
awk -vFPAT='[[:digit:]]+\\.' 'NF{$1=$1; print}' file
14. 20.
1. 1.
2. 2.
3. 3.
```